# Java: wrapping one entity class in another entity class

Tags: java, api, parameters, get

i was trying to pass two parameters into the rest template execute method in the request GET body.

The API passes two parameter values

```
http://localhost:8080/api/likes/user?likes=xyz&user=abc
```

There are two entity class

```
public class Account{
public String user;
public String date;
public List<PostList> post;}
```

And PostList entity class

```
public class PostList{
public int likes;
public String comment;
public int shares;
}
```

I want to pass user from the Account class and Likes from Post_List class in the request get call

How could I wrap that in a class and pass the value?

```
public List<Account> getRatingViaApi(......//wrapper class){
    
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        //String resourceUrl = "http://localhost:8080/movies";
    
        
        RequestCallback requestCallback = request -> {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                mapper.writeValue(request.getBody(), 
                        //Wrapper class);

                request.getHeaders()
                 .setAccept(Arrays.asList(
                         MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, 
                         MediaType.ALL));
                };

        
        ResponseExtractor<List<Account>> responseExtractor = response -> 
ObjectMapper mapper= new ObjectMapper ();

                return mapper.readValue(response.getBody(),new TypeReference<List<Account>>(){});
             };

        restTemplate.execute(resourceUrl, 
            HttpMethod.GET, 
            requestCallback, 
            responseExtractor );    
}
```

If there exist a post

```
[
 {
  "user":"o1",
  "date":"01-03-2022",
  "post":[
        {
       "likes":"1",
       "comment":"abdc",
       "shares":"5"
       }
    ]
 }
]
```

If there exist no post

```
[
 {
  "user":null
  "date":null
  "post":null
 }
]
```

I check these return values

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. All names should be camelCase not snake_case

Comment: Yes edited it,i hope it's fine now

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am trying to wrap those two classes in one entity class and trying to get only those specific values @Tim

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/api/likes/user?likes=xyz&user=abc` these are query parameters so you just need to update the `xyz` and `abc` with the values from the User and PostList class.

Comment: @Tim i have edited the code to give a better idea on the code. So here when I call request call back I'm passing in the two values in the ObjectMapper.writeValue

Comment: What are you expecting to get back once calling `http://localhost:8080/api/likes/user?likes=xyz&user=abc`?

Comment: I have edited the code,these are the responses i get from the api

Comment: In essence, the API returns List<Account>. I'm not sure why you would be using the `execute` method, just use the `getForEntity`. Have a look and try this [GET request](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template#2-retrieving-pojo-instead-of-json). Also note that RestTemplate is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, and if i wanted to store the response in the entity class directly, i would have to make the response type as the entity class, i could access the value directly from the POJO then? @tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can have a method to create the url with updated query params. Keeping it simple, can look something like such:

```
private String createUrlForUserLikes(final Account account, final PostList postList) {
    return String.format("http://localhost:8080/api/likes/user?likes=%s&user=%s", postList.likes(), account.user());
}
```

Comment: So i just refer this method in place where url is called, right?

Comment: Yes, and pass in the Account and PostList.

Can modify  it as needed, but just as an idea.

Comment: when I'm passing it in the request body, i would have to pass the value right, and for that i would have to create a wrapper class? @Tim

Comment: A GET request does not have a request body, so what are you referring to when you say request body?

Comment: i have edited the post with the code, I'm passing the two parameters in the request all back in the object mapper.writevalue @Tim